# Remove StaticMesh via debug console in ue4

Tags: unreal-4, debugging

How do I in game dev build debug console:

- list scene meshes
- remove exact mesh causing perfomance hit?

tried:

- `show StaticMesh` removes all meshes
- https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/TestingAndOptimization/PerformanceAndProfiling/Overview
- https://docs.unrealengine.com/udk/Three/ConsoleCommands.html

ue 4.25

Comment: Is there another way, like setting RenderOpacity to 0? How?

Answer (score 0):

```
getall actor
destroyall <actor_name_or_class>
```